# Insert missing records from one table to another SQL - stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

New to SQL developing & stored procedures. I have a source table A and target table B. I need to insert table A's data into table B making changes.

If the source table doesn't have the record 1 for `GL_PERIOD` column for each customer code, then insert it into Table B WITH `gl_period = 1` for the missing customer code along with other records.

From below image `Gl_period` of AMETOW doesn't have record GL_RECORD = 1 , but ATTSER has GL_RECORD = 1.

I need to insert data into table B for the records the doesn't have GL_PERIOD = 1 for AMETOW (and others) also insert all other records that has GL_PERIOD 2,3,4 etc.

TABLE B OUTPUT should be

```
AMETOW, AmericanTower, NULL, 1, NULL, NULL, NULL,0,0,0,0,0
AMETOW, AmericanTower, NULL, 2, NULL, NULL, NULL,0,0,0,0,0
AMETOW, AmericanTower, NULL, 3, NULL, NULL, NULL,0,0,0,0,0
AMETOW, AmericanTower, NULL, 4, NULL, NULL, NULL,0,0,0,0,0
```

Thanks in advance, please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: please provide database structure and sample data ~

Comment: What would be helpful would be sample data in both tables as well as details on what you have already tried.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Please find the stored procedure i have written.